# How to place an image on top of a background image on a webpage

Tags: html, css, image

[image]I'm trying to create a webpage that has a background image and then just underneath my nav bar have a sort of cover image that sits just underneath it.

I have managed to get a background image but then the next image just sits at the bottom of the page.

I've tried looking at a few posts and tutorials on how to do this but the same keeps happening.

**Code Snippet Demonstration :**

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  height: 100 vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

#wrapper {
  width: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

#row, #logo {
  border: 1px;
  float: left;
  min-height: 150px;
  color: white;
}

#row {
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
}

.main-nav {
  float: center;
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 350px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a: hover {
  border: 1px solid white;
}

#logo img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 145px;
  float: left;
  padding-left: 10%;
}

body {
  /*background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5),rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),url(hockey.jpg);*/
  background-size: cover;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

hr {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: #fff;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-top: 0px;
}

.instagram img {
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 960px;
}

.twitter img {
  width: 65px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding-left: 30px;
}

body, html {
  height: 100%;
}

.bg {
  /* The image used */
  background-image: url(https://goravens.ca/wp-content/themes/goravens/images/events/womens-hockey-3.jpg);

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%;

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

/*
h1 {
  color:white;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 275px;
  padding-left:150px;
}
*/
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="logo">
      <img src="logo.png">
    </div>
    <div id="row">
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="/Users/jenny/Desktop/SCHOOL/COMPUTER SCIENCE/HOME.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/jenny/Desktop/SCHOOL/COMPUTER SCIENCE/PHOTOS.html">PHOTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/jenny/Desktop/SCHOOL/COMPUTER SCIENCE/PLAYERS.html">PLAYERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/jenny/Desktop/SCHOOL/COMPUTER SCIENCE/NEWS.html">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/Users/jenny/Desktop/SCHOOL/COMPUTER SCIENCE/SCHEDULE.html">SCHEDULE</a></li>
      </ul>
      <br>
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="block_1"></div>
    <hr>
    <ul class="instagram">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/embrunpanthers/"><img src="instagram.png"></a>
    </ul>
    <ul class="twitter">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/NCJHLEmbrun?lang=en"><img src="twitter.png"></a>
    </ul>
  </div>
</header>
<img src='https://cdn.hockeycanada.ca/hockey-canada/Team-Canada/Men/World-Cup/2016/sep_29_wch_team.jpg'>
```

Comment: changed that, but the same issue still occurs

Comment: Why you used `space` between dash in `css` syntax? like `min - height` ?? Also you have many wrong `html` code.

Comment: There is no `-` selector in CSS, but it appears the intention was to write `.main - nav` as `.main-nav` (joining the selectors and removing the space). Consider improving this question by: **1.** Correcting syntax errors of this nature, **2.** combining both `css` styles and `html` markup into an embedded code snippet (the `<>` icon in the text editor with other formatting options like **bold** and *italics*), **3.** tidying up syntax for improved readability (this can be easily accomplished within the aforementioned code snippet)

Comment: One of the *various* ways the community helps people when they have issues is by pointing out flaws in any given code included in the problem statement. You can view this as "criticising" or you can view this as "assisting" - this is wholly up to you.

Comment: I was referring to Mr.x's comment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should get rid of the floats. They just make reasoning about the page more difficult, at least for me.
I used the flexbox feature of css to position elements within the header. You can read more on this here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/[enter link description here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

I still wasn't sure if you want the header to be at the top and then disappear when you scroll down or rather if you want it to float over the content and stay at the top even if you scroll down. Therefore I left a comment in css - uncomment it to see the other option.

HTML:

```
 <body>
  <div class="bg">
    <header>
      <div class="logoContainer">
        <img src="http://www.catster.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/A-fluffy-cat-looking-funny-surprised-or-concerned.jpg">
      </div>
      <ul class="main-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PHOTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">PLAYERS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NEWS</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">SCHEDULE</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
    <div class="socialLinksContainer">
      <div class="instagram">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://static.pexels.com/photos/104827/cat-pet-animal-domestic-104827.jpeg"></a>
      </div>
      <div class="twitter">
        <a href="#"><img src="https://www.petmd.com/sites/default/files/petmd-cat-happy-13.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
    Main content goes here
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
    header {
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  //uncomment this for the header to float over the content
  //position: fixed;
  //top: 10px;
}

.logoContainer {
  height: 10vh;
}

.logoContainer > img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.main-nav {
  list-style: none;
  margin-top: 100 px;
  margin-left: 350 px;
}

.main-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.main-nav li a {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 5 px 10 px;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans - serif;
  font-size: 15 px;
}

.main-nav li.active a {
  border: 1 px solid white;
}

.main-nav li a: hover {
  border: 1 px solid white;
}

# logo img {
  width: 150 px;
  height: 145 px;
  padding-left: 10 %;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: red;
}

hr {
  width: 100 %;
  height: 1 px;
  background: #fff
}

.socialLinksContainer {
  position: fixed;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.title {
  position: relative;
  width: 1200 px;
  margin-left: 0 px;
  margin-top: 0 px;
}

.instagram > a > img {
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10 px;
  padding-left: 960 px;
}

.twitter img {
  max-width: 30px;
  max-height: 30px;
  margin-top: 10 px;
  padding-left: 30 px;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100 %;
}

body {
  background-image: url('https://cdn.hockeycanada.ca/hockey-canada/Team-Canada/Men/World-Cup/2016/sep_29_wch_team.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.imageUnderTheNavbar {
  max-height: 50px;
}
```

Please take a look at this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5ufpomy4/4/

Is this something that you had in mind?

Comment: The background image is how i wanted it, but im trying to get another image to appear just underneath the nav bar within the main body of the page if that makes sense.

Comment: I updated the fiddle by adding an image right under the header. If this is not what you want then I don't know. Maybe do you want the navbar to kind of float over the content of the page? Please explain again or draw a simple picture of what you want to achieve.

Comment: Yeah close, just in the center and spread across the same length as the nav bar, like a cover image. and to have the nav links to float to the right so the logo is on its own on the left if that makes more sense?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused. If you want me to help you, please just draw a simple image of what you need.

Comment: I've added a picture to the original post

Comment: I updated my answer, the code and the fiddle. Hope this is finally what you need :)

Comment: Thank you that's perfect... why when i copy this into notepadd++ does it change though?

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean. Make sure you are not missing anything. Maybe some silly copy-paste error?

Comment: Did you get it to work? Btw. consider marking the answer as the accepted solution :) Thanks.